# IF $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ Show that , $\sup _{A\in \mathbb{R}}|\mu_n -\mu |\rightarrow0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning, characteristic-functions

Let $\mu_n ,  $  be probability measures  on $( \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{R})$ with $n \geq 1$ with charachterstic functions ${\Phi}_n$.

$\mu$  is also a probability measure with function  $g$

Given that

$|{\Phi}_n (t)| \leq  g(t)$ $\forall t \in  \mathbb{R}$

and    $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)dt< \infty $

If $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ Show that ,
$\sup _{A\in \mathbb{R}}|\mu_n  -\mu |\rightarrow0$ (i.e $\mu_n$  converges in $\mu$ in total variation norm)

My thought was to use try to use Levy continuity theorem. Or maybe sheffe's Theorem (See below).
But I am not sure how.
[image]

Comment: In what sense is $\mu_n$ converging to $\mu$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the proof of the statement along the lines of the OP's ideas:

- The assumptions on the characteristic functions imply that all the $\Phi_n$ are integrable.
- Since $\mu_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\mu$, $\Phi_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} g$ pointwise (in fact uniformly in campsite sets ue to Lévy's continuity theorem).
- By dominate convergence ($|\Phi_n|\leq |g|$), $\|\Phi_n -g\|_{L_1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.
- The Fourier [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) theorem, $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are absolutely convergent with respect to Lebesgue's measure $\lambda$, and if $f_n=\frac{d\mu_n}{d\lambda}$ and $f=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$ are the densities of $\mu_n$ and $\mu$,
  $$
  \begin{align}
  f_n(y)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-ity}\Phi_n(t)\,dt\qquad \lambda\quad\text{a.s.}\\
  f(y)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-ity}g(t)\,dt\qquad \lambda\quad\text{a.s.}
  \end{align}
  $$
  Furthermore, the Fourier inversion theorem also implies the there are continuous functions $\bar{f}_n$ and $\bar{f}$ such that $f_n=\bar{f}_n$ and $f=\bar{f}$.
- Again, by dominated convergence $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow} f$ $\mu$-a.s.
- The conclusion now follows from Scheffe's theorem. (I provide a version of it and a short proof below)

---

**Theorem:** Let $\{\mu,\mu_n\}_n$ be finite
measures (positive) such that $\lim_n\mu_n(\Omega)=\mu(\Omega)$. Let
$\nu$ be a $\sigma$--finite measure and suppose
that $\mu_n,\,\mu\ll \nu$.
If $\tfrac{d\mu_n}{d\nu}\rightarrow\tfrac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ $\nu$--a.s. then,
$\|\mu_n-\mu\|_{TV}\rightarrow0$.

Proof:

If $\mu(\Omega)=0$, then the proof is trivial since
$\|\mu_n\|_{TV}=\mu_n(\Omega)\rightarrow0$.

If $\mu(\Omega)>0$, let   $\mu'_n=
\tfrac{\mu(\Omega)}{\mu_n(\Omega)}\mu_n$ so that
that $\mu'_n(\Omega)=\mu(\Omega)$. Hence, if
$f_n=\tfrac{d\mu'_n}{d\nu}$ and
$f=\tfrac{d\mu}{d\nu}$, then $\int(f-f_n)_+\,d\nu=\int(f-f_n)_-\,d\nu=\tfrac12
\int|f-f_n|\,d\nu=\tfrac12\|\mu-\mu'_n\|_{TV}$.

Since
$(f-f_n)_+\leq f$, dominated convergence implies that
$\|\mu'_n-\mu\|_{TV}\rightarrow0$. As
$$
\|\mu_n-\mu'_n\|_{TV}\leq \Big|\frac{\mu(\Omega)}{\mu_n(\Omega)}-1\Big|\sup_n\|\mu_n\|_{TV}\rightarrow0,
$$
we conclude that $\|\mu_n-\mu\|_{TV}\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 1):

By inversion formula for characteristic functions the fact that the characteristic functions are integrable implies that they are absolutely continuous. Note that the characteristic function of $\mu$ is also dominted by the same integrable function $g$ so $\mu$ also has  a density. Let $f_n$ and $f$ be the densities of $\mu_n$ and $\mu$.   Then $f_n \to f$ a.e. by DCT applied to the inversion formula. Finally Scheffe's Lemma show that $\int |f_n-f| \to 0$. Of course, $|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)| \leq \int |f_n-f|$ for all $A$.

Inversion formula: if characteristic function $\phi$ of $\mu$ is integrable then $\mu$ has  density $f$ given by $f(x)=\frac 1 {2\pi} \int e^{-itx} \phi(x)dx$.

Comment: Reference for Scheffe's Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma

Comment: Could you clarify:1) Given $|{\Phi}_n (t)| \leq  g(t)$ $\forall t \in  \mathbb{R}$ and    $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)dt< \infty $ we get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |{\Phi}_n (t)|dt< \infty $  which means it is absolutely continuous ? 2) Could you show the next  part Analytically please? :  Then $f_n \to f$ a.e. by DCT applied to the inversion formula . Lastly 3)  the final conclusion $\sup _{A\in \mathbb{R}}|\mu_n  -\mu |\rightarrow0$ (i.e $\mu_n$  = $frac 1 {2} $\int |f_n-f|dγ \to 0$ ? If it is possible could you show step (2) and (3)   Because I am self learning and I will be more confident.

Comment: If it is more suitable for you using paper for the additional explanation I mentioned above, you could send or upload ( written on the paper explanation )

Comment: @xiao The inversion formula I have quoted can be found in K L Chung's book (and many other books). The proof of this includes  the proof that density exists (i.e. CDF is absolutely continuous).  $f_n(x)=\int e^{-itx} \Phi_n(x)dx  \to \int e^{-itx} \Phi(x)dx=f(x)$ because   $\Phi_n(x) \to \Phi (x)$ and $|e^{itx}|=1$ so the integrand is dominated by $g$. $|\mu_n(A)-\mu (A)|=|\int_A |f_n(x)-f(x)|dx \leq \int_{\mathbb R} |f_n(x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$.